# Spying on functions called by angular.js $interval during unit tests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Having trouble testing a function called by $interval.

In a nutshell:

```
angular.module('services', [])
  .factory('someFactory', [function () {
    function someFunction () { console.log('someFunction called'); }
    $interval(someFunction, 100);

    return {
      someFunction: someFunction
    }
  }]);

describe('someFactory', function () {
  it('should call someFunction', function () {
    spyOn(someFactory, 'someFunction');
    $interval.flush(150);
    // someFactory.someFunction() // will pass when uncommented
    expect(someFactory.someFunction).toHaveBeenCalled(); // FAIL
  );
});
```

In both cases, 'someFunction called' is logged to the console, so flush is calling the function, but the spy can't see it when the function is applied by the $interval.

Angular 1.2 and Jasmine 1.3

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add any relevant beforeEach setup code to above? Looks like a scope/injection problem but can't tell from just above. If you comment out the flush line does the console still show the log line?

Comment: See: http://plnkr.co/edit/7DAQuShNNSWEe9BWe1vQ?p=info

With thanks to a helpful person in the IRC channel

Comment: updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/84HCKOA0Sfyb9SKXAUnk

Answer (score 0):

*someFunction* you are spying on is the one returned in the object literal. *someFunction* called by $interval is the private function declared within the factory. You *could* do something like `$interval(this.someFunction, 100);` to get it working.

On a side note, in the example in the update plunker it seems that you're testing interaction between methods of the same class (mocking someFunction). IMO since the scope of the unit test is a class, you shouldn't mock that class' functions. You should test the output or side effect of your method call, e.g. in the example above test that `console.log` was called after 100ms, not that $interval was invoked.